# Login with Facebook does not redirects to .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am creating a facebook application in asp.net.

I want that when user login with facebook it should not redirects to Facebook.com but to the aspx page in my application.

Currently, I have a page called `Login.aspx` and i am using a code for login, when user click on login button, a pop up dialog box appears in which it asks for email id and password just like facebook.

Then when i click on log in it redirects to the same aspx page(`Login.aspx`). But i want that it should redirect to another aspx page(`List.aspx`).

Here is my code for login:

HTML:

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="window.location.reload()"></fb:login-button>
```

I don't know how to redirect it to `List.aspx`.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Gurbax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in CS, You can redirect using

```
Page.Response.Redirect("List.aspx");
```

in JS, you can redirect using

```
window.location = "List.aspx"
```

EDIT:

If i'm getting it correctly, what you're looking for is

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="window.location = 'List.aspx'"></fb:login-button>
```